# h1 background color won't stretch to image width

Tags: html, css, background, stretch

Here is my HTML & CSS respectively:

**HTML**

```
<section class="slider">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 column">
      <div style="position:relative">
        <img src="img/code.jpg" alt="Code Image">
        <h1><span>slider title</span></h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
 h1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

h1 span {
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(30, 59, 69, 0.8);
}
```

And here is a screenshot via Imgur, of what my page looks like currently: [image]

I'm trying to set the blue strip behind "slider title" to stretch across the entire width of the image beind. Am I missing something at all? I've tried a few different methods but nothing appears to work :(

Comment: Spans are by default `inline` elements, you can either add 'display:block' to the h1 span or make it a div which is by befault a `block` element.

Comment: Correct good sir! Thank you very much :)

Comment: just FYI h1's are also block elements by default, so you might be able to cleanup some markup by removing the span while you're at it.

Comment: okay, so I could just chuck all the span CSS into the h1 CSS?

Comment: I added an answer that contains what I would do with the h1. You can clean things up a bit, and save yourself from a couple headaches when you want to use an h1 someplace else.

Comment: @ChrisHazell you can accept eric's answer by clicking the tick beside the answer. It appears on hover. 15 points for him and 2 for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spans are by default inline elements, you can either add 'display:block' to the h1 span or make it a div which is by default a block element.

I would also probably modify the code to make things easier down the road when you want to use an h1 tag someplace else.

HTML:

```
<section class="slider">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 column">
      <div style="position:relative">
        <img src="img/code.jpg" alt="Code Image">
        <h1 class='slide-title'>slider title</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.slide-title {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(30, 59, 69, 0.8);
}
```